# How to publish multiple messages at once (batch processing) using Google Cloud PubSub's console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-console

I could successfully publish one message at a time on Google Cloud Pubsub using the console, and the result shows up in a table in BigQuery.

```
{"ID": 123, "Item1": "aaa", "Item2": "bbb"}
```

BigQuery Table:

| ID | Item1 | Item2 |

| 123 | aaa | bbb |

How can I publish multiple messages at once through the console? I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
[{"ID": 123, "Item1": "aaa", "Item2": "bbb"}, {"ID": 123, "Item1": "aaa", "Item2": "bbb"}, {"ID": 123, "Item1": "aaa", "Item2": "bbb"}]
```

This is for a demo so I only want to use the console. Thank you!

Comment: I would like to point out that I changed the IDs in the messages, so they are not duplicates.      [{ "ID": 123, "Item1": "aaa", "Item2": "bbb"},  { "ID": 456, "Item1": "aaa", "Item2": "bbb"},  { "ID": 789, "Item1": "aaa", "Item2": "bbb"}]  

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using the GCP console you can only publish one test message at a time.  If you want to publish a group of messages, you could write a custom application.  However, perhaps an easier story is to use the GCP SDK with the gcloud command.

See [gcloud pubsub topics publish](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/topics/publish)

You could script the execution of this command to run it once per message.

Remember that from the GCP Console, you can also have a Cloud Shell instance from which you can run the `gcloud` command.

Comment: Thank you very much!  We do have a custom app - this is for demo purpose. Seems like to can't publish multiple messages then.

Comment: Howdy my friend.  To the very best of my knowledge, the Cloud Console allows us to publish one message at a time.    The Cloud Console ability to publish messages is a simple test tool.  It isn't meant to be particularly rich in function.

If it were me and I needed to post multiple messages to Pub/Sub at one time and wanted to do that exclusively through a browser mechanism.  I might create a Cloud Function that takes a POST REST input containing a JSON array and publish each message in the array and then use a tool like Postman to submit the REST request.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Kolban! Will try it out!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little script (of your preferred language), maybe reading from a json or csv and publishing using the batch setting. See the docs.

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/batch-messaging#python